# Why are those definitions not legal in C?

Tags: c, constants, global, variable-assignment, variable-length-array

I'm reading a book about C and I don't understand this concept:

> *Another common misconception is thinking of a const qualified variable as a constant expression. In C, const means "read-only", not "compile time constant". So, global definitions like const int SIZE = 10; int global_arr[SIZE]; and const int SIZE = 10; int global_var = SIZE; are not legal in C.*

I also don't understand very good the diference between const variable and constant expression. All const variables are constant expressions, right? I have readed other questions about this topic but I still without understantig. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212323/discussion-on-question-by-william94-why-are-those-definitions-not-legal-in-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have

```
int a = 42;
const int *b = &a;
```

now `*b` is `const` ie *read-only*. You are not allowed to change `*b` without casting the `const` away (thanks Eric Postpischil)

```
// *b = -1; // not allowed
a = -1;
printf("%d\n", *b); // print -1
```

The point is: the value of a `const` qualified object **may** change. A constant value **never** changes.

Comment: I don't think that's what that passage is referring to. I think it's just talking about how 'const qualified variables' cannot be used in places where c expects a constant 'expression', like e.g. a 'literal'.

Comment: Also you can have `const volatile` objects!!

Comment: Re “You are not allowed to change *b”: After `int a = 42; const int *b = &a;`, the behavior of `* (char *) b = 73;` is defined by the C standard, as is that of `* (char *) &*b = 73;`.

Answer (score 0):

What they basically mean is, In C it is illegal to use a `const` qualified variable to initialize another variable or determine the size of an array with it at global scope, like for example:

```
const int SIZE = 5;
int a = SIZE;              // This is not allowed.
int b[SIZE];               // This is also not allowed.

int main(void)
{
   ...
}
```

This is because variables and arrays at global scope need to be determinate at *compilation time*. A `const` qualified variable is still a variable and the values of variables are computed/evaluated at *run-time*.

A *macro constant*, which is a "compile time constant" could be used for this like f.e.:

```
#define SIZE 15

int a[SIZE];             // This is ok.
int b = SIZE;            // This is ok, too.
```

---

> I also don't understand very good the difference between `const` variable and constant expression. All `const` variables are constant expressions, right?

No.

Quote from ISO:IEC 9899/2018 (C18), Section 6.6/2:

> "*A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.*"

A constant expression is a literal expression which always get evaluated to the same value - the evaluated value is constant. Therefore it can be evaluated at compile time.

F.e.:

```
5 + 4
```

is always 9 and can therefore be evaluated at compilation time.

Whereas a `const` variable:

```
const int SIZE = 5;
```

or

```
(const int SIZE 5;)

5 + 9 + SIZE;
```

is not a constant expression as it implies a variable. Although the variable `SIZE` is qualified by `const` (which means that it can´t be modified after initialization), it is not a constant expression, because a variable, does not matter if it `const` or not, is computed/evaluated at run-time.

A `const` qualified variable is not nor can be a part of a constant expression.

Comment: But if: const int a = 10; The value of the constant a is not a constant expression? Now I belive that I can't do that also: int variable a = 3; int global_array[a]. But I can do that: int global_array[3+2*2]; I am right?

Comment: @William94 In the C language, const variables are unfortunately still treated as variables, in C++ on the other hand you actually _**can**_ use a const as the size of an array or to initialize a global variable. Edit: And yes, you can use something like `3+2*2` as the size of an array

Comment: @William94 "*The value of the constant a is not a constant expression?*" No, because the value of `a` is evaluated at run-time. - You can do `int variable a = 3; int global_array[a]` as `a` isn´t qualified by `const`. You could for example do this too: `int gloabl_array[a+2+b];`.

Comment: It is not **illegal** to use a `const` object as an initializer even for static objects. It is not defined as part of strictly conforming C, but C implementations may support it.

Comment: The determining factor in whether an initializer must be a *constant expression* is whether it is for an object with static or thread storage duration, not whether the declaration appears at global scope. See C 2018 6.7.9 4. The C standard has nothing called “global scope,” and that is a misnomer as it would mean visible throughout the entire program, not just external to any function. Thus, it would apply only to identifiers with external linkage, but static objects with internal linkage require *constant expressions* too.

Comment: Re “A constant expression is a literal expression which always get evaluated to the same value”: Maybe within one compilation and link (including run-time linking and loading) in a specific context, but not **always**. Address constants may be used in initializers but can vary between links, even between program executions. `sizeof` values may differ between C implementations, and `__LINE__` changes throughout a translation unit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil To 1.: I guess that´s why my experiment as discussed in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49194995#49194995) providing such results. So, the book is wrong?

Comment: The book is wrong in multiple regards. If an object is defined with `const`, the C standard does not define the behavior of attempting to modify it. For objects defined without `const`, having some `const` qualified reference to them is largely just advisory—you may cast it away `const` and modify the object. `const` serves to help communicate and avoid mistakes, but it is not a rigid barrier. As for what are *constant expressions*, the C standard defines things that must be supported as constant expressions, such as things computed purely from values, but implementations can support more.

Comment: So that explains why a C compiler may allow `static const int x = 3; static int y = x;`.